# Python Loop to move files

Tags: python, file, move

Once again, I am looking for some assiatance, thanks in advance. This code has the purpouse to move files in a list, from one folder to another.
It is giving me the ERROR below.

```
import shutil
Import os
source='/dev/sdc /mnt/mnttensor/Dhole/'
destination='/home/ubuntu/classificator/nodhole/'
fo = open("dhole3.txt", "r")
content = fo.readlines()
for files in content:
   shutil.move(source+files,destination+files)
```

ERROR

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 130, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/sdc /mnt/mnttensor/Dhole/227_5267_M0423_19Oct12-IMAG0068.JPG\r\n'
```

I would really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Is the `source` correct? Or is it two different `sources`?

Comment: You have a `space` in your souce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the erroneous directory:

```
/dev/sdc /mnt/mnttensor/Dhole/227_5267_M0423_19Oct12-IMAG0068.JPG\r\n
```

Notice the `\r\n` at the end of the file. This is what most likely has caused the error, and this should be fixed by using a `rstrip()` method inside of the for-loop so it truncates the special characters when the `shutil.move()` method tries to find the files. So the for loop should look something like this:

```
for files in content:
   shutil.move(source + files.rstrip("\r\n"), destination + files.rstrip("\r\n"))
```

Also notice the whitespace character at the `/dev/sdc` directory – that is likely unintentional and should probably be removed.

Comment: you might want to use `.rstrip('\r\n')` instead of `[:-2]` as some other lines in the files might not contain those characters.

Comment: I am realatively new into this web page. I want to vote positevely to those that answered, but I am not sure if i did it well.